# Código VBA não quer rodar na aba desejada

Tags: vba

Bom dia a todos, me desculpe pela desatenção com a lingua.

Estou tentando escrever um código que lê uma tabela na aba "Premissas". A tabela tem 3 colunas que estou salvando em 3 vetores para construir outra tabela em uma aba que eu chamo de "XX", na qual eu incluí o módulo. Entretanto, o código roda quando tenho selecionado a aba "Premissas", o que não me serve, enquanto na aba "XX" (onde estou colocando um botão) o código para na seguinte linha:

```
Array_usina = Worksheets("Premissas").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(LR, 2)).Value
```

A parte do código que menciono se encontra abaixo:

```
Sub gerar_dados()
Dim Array_usina() As Variant
Dim Array_circ() As Variant
Dim Array_trecho() As Variant


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


        LR = Worksheets("Premissas").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'last item in row #2
        Array_usina = Worksheets("Premissas").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(LR, 2)).Value
        Array_circ = Worksheets("Premissas").Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(LR, 3)).Value
        Array_trecho = Worksheets("Premissas").Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(LR, 4)).Value
```

O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está pegando a última linha da aba "XX", tente `Worksheets("Premissas").Cells(Worksheets("Premissas").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` e nas células dentro de `Range()`, também estão sem referência `Worksheets("Premissas").Cells(4, 2)`

Ou para melhorar o código e também deixar mais elegante, você pode declarar a planilha e utilizar um `With`:

```
Sub gerar_dados()
    Dim Array_usina() As Variant
    Dim Array_circ() As Variant
    Dim Array_trecho() As Variant
    Dim Premissas As Worksheet


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo SairCodigo
    Set Premissas = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Premissas")

    With Premissas
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'last item in row #2
        Array_usina = .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(LR, 2)).Value
        Array_circ = .Range(.Cells(4, 3), .Cells(LR, 3)).Value
        Array_trecho = .Range(.Cells(4, 4), .Cells(LR, 4)).Value
    End With

SairCodigo:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Se houver erro, mostra mensagem
    If Err.Description <> "" Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, _
               vbExclamation + vbOKCancel, _
               "Error: " & CStr(Err.Number)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Boa tarde! Agradeço pela resposta. 
Tentei ambas as soluções e continua dando o seguinte erro na mesma linha que informei na pergunta.

Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: @BrunoMA Veja o edit